# Twice a where in a survey

Tags: php, sql

Instead of wanting the whole table i only want one result based on a link.

This works:

```
$BANDID = intval($_GET['BANDID']);
$sql = "SELECT 
            BANDID, 
            NAAMBAND, 
            CONTACTBAND, 
            GENRE, 
            OMSCHRIJVING, 
            LEDEN, 
            PLAATS, 
            PRIJS, 
            BOEKERID, 
            WEBSITE, 
            YOUTUBE, 
            NOTITIES  
        FROM 
            `BANDS` 
        WHERE 
            BANDID = $BANDID";
```

$BANDID is get by clicking a link on a previous page, but i wanted it combined the above

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            NAAM,
            BANDID, 
            NAAMBAND, 
            CONTACTBAND, 
            BOEKERID
        FROM 
            `BANDS` 
        INNER JOIN 
            `adres` 
        WHERE 
            `BANDS`.BOEKERID = `adres`.id ";
```

but this doenst work:

```
$BANDID = intval($_GET['BANDID']);
$sql1 = "SELECT 
            NAAM,
            BANDID, 
            NAAMBAND, 
            CONTACTBAND, 
            BOEKERID 
        FROM 
            `BANDS` 
        INNER JOIN 
            `adres` 
        WHERE 
            `BANDS`.BOEKERID = `adres`.id 
        WHERE 
            BANDID = $BANDID";
```

Please help me further, thks

Comment: does it return any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE `BANDS`.BOEKERID = `adres`.id WHERE BANDID=$BANDID";
```

replace second where with AND

```
WHERE `BANDS`.BOEKERID = `adres`.id AND BANDID=$BANDID";
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use ON and combine it with WHERE like this:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT NAAM,BANDID, NAAMBAND, CONTACTBAND, BOEKERID 
         FROM `BANDS` INNER JOIN `adres` 
         ON `BANDS`.BOEKERID = `adres`.id
         WHERE BANDID=$BANDID";
```

That's how you do proper joins.

Comment: Both other answers will works but this is the best (and the most correct) way to do what you want

Comment: @GaspardRosay Yup, that's why I said this is the proper way. There are many ways to achieve the same results.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change to proper join syntax.  Every join needs an ON clause and then you can put your WHERE clause below that.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT  NAAM,BANDID, NAAMBAND, CONTACTBAND, BOEKERID 
         FROM `BANDS` 
         INNER JOIN `adres` 
           ON`BANDS`.BOEKERID = `adres`.id 
         WHERE BANDID=$BANDID";
```

Comment: it happen from time to time =)